# Почему переменная сеанса не передаётся в мастерпэйдж со страницы авторизации?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Авторизация. Страница Login, если введённые логин/пароль есть в БД, создаёт auth = "1" в Session. В Site.Master есть скрытая asp-таблица и при загрузке страницы проводится проверка, равно ли auth "1", если равно - открывает таблицу... но... не открывает... :( Объясните, что делаю не так? (VS 2010, .NET 4)

**Login.aspx**

```
...
<asp:TextBox ID="txb_login" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txb_pass" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btn_ok" runat="server" Text="Вход" OnClick="btn_ok_Click" />
...
```

**Login.aspx.cs**

```
...
protected void btn_ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //проверка на наличие совпадений введённых логина/пароля с записью в БД
    ...
    if (chk == "1")
    {
        Session["auth"] = "1";
        lbl_status.Text = "Авторизован!";
    }
    else
    {
        Session["auth"] = "0";
        lbl_status.Text = "Не авторизован!";
    }
}
...
```

**Site.Master**

```
...
<asp:Table ID="tbl_admin" runat="server" Visible="false">
</asp:Table>
...
```

**Site.Master.cs**

```
...
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    auth = (string)(Session["Authorized"]);
    if (auth == "1")
    {
        tbl_admin.Visible = true;
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Text = "TEST!";
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
        tbl_admin.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    else tbl_admin.Visible = false;
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что бросается в глаза сразу:

Session**["auth"]** = "1";

и

auth = (string)(Session**["Authorized"]**);

Записываем енотов проверяем бибизянов... Остальное вроде ок. ASP насколько я помню инициализирует сессии самостоятельно, вручную ничего делать не нужно...

Comment: Ах, как же так... Прошу прощения.

Огромное спасибо - работает! :)